# More info when you click a field in a subform table in pop up form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to get a window to popup when you click that small box beside a field in my subform table, and then click the button "more info". This form would pop up with all the extra information about that record; in text boxes so you can edit it. On this form it pops out, it only has a button that has back and when you click back, it saves all the changes made in the text boxes in the record you were viewing more information about... and updates it. It then brings back up the previous form, and updates the subform on that form so it shows all changes made to the table. I am not looking for the More Info button to show more info for all records. I am looking for it to bring up more info for that one record you selected only, and to get more info on another, you must click back and select a new one. How would I go about setting up the More Info button so it pops up the new form with the information?

For an example of what I mean by pressing the more info button, here is a picture:

In the picture, it is a table. Clicking that small space highlights the whole record, and you are able to push DEL on your keyboard to delete the record (though that doesn't matter in the case, just pointing out it's a table.)

[image]

---

Code I have in my More Info button:

```
    Private Sub CustomerMoreInfoBtn_Click()
   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "CustomerInfoF"
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "CustomerMoreInfoQ"
   On Error GoTo Err_CustomerMoreInfoBtn_Click

   Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
   Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("CustomerMoreInfoQ", _
                                       "SELECT * " & _
                                       "FROM CustomersT " & _
                                       "WHERE CustomerID = " & txtCustID.Value)
   DoCmd.OpenForm "CustomerInfoF"

Exit_CustomerMoreInfoBtn_Click:
   Exit Sub
Err_CustomerMoreInfoBtn_Click:
   MsgBox Err.Description
   Resume Exit_CustomerMoreInfoBtn_Click
End Sub
```

Code in the form it self:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "CustomerMoreInfoQ"
End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the code that you currently have in the `On Click` event for your "More Info" button....

Comment: This was more of a statement than a question...  But I'm not sure if you can make it so just that small space is clicked.  I know for a fact you can highlight a record and then pull that.  Maybe edit to actually ask a question and give a little more detail about the form (like is this a listbox, combobox, or a table)

Comment: Edited. Gord, currently there is no code at all in the On Click event, or any event for that matter. I've tried a bunch of things, but none worked at all so I scrapped them all.

Comment: Gord may have a different solution, but I would use the `On Click` and have it populate a new, 2nd form with a what's called a Recordset.  Then you can use `.Edit` and `.Update` to modify the existing record.

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying this in the first place, and I will edit the OP to say this as well; but I am not looking for the More Info button to show more info for all records. I am looking for it to bring up more info for that one record you selected only, and to get more info on another, you must click back and select a new one.

Comment: That's what my method proposes.  You would click More Info, it would pass the highlighted record.  Then with an `On_Click()` for the More Info button, you add `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open the 2nd form and pass the unique ID as an args.  The opened form then pulls that specific record on `Form_Load()` with a SQL statement and recordset.  This gives you only one record to work with (the one you selected in the original form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below example your button is named `cmdMoreInfo`.  When you click on the button it creates the `MyCustDetail` query based on the value of the customer id.  Then it opens the `frm_CustDetailEdit` form.  Set the forms ***Record Source*** to `MyCustDetail`.

In order to be able to create the query it must not already exist.  Therefore, I check beforehand and delete it if it exists.  Also, when closing the main form it also will delete the query since it would no longer be needed anyway.

```
Private Sub cmdMoreInfo_Click()
   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm_CustDetailEdit"
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "MyCustDetail"
   On Error GoTo Err_cmdMoreInfo_Click

   Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
   Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("MyCustDetail", _
                                  "SELECT * " & _
                                  "FROM tbl_Customer " & _
                                  "WHERE CustomerID = " & txtCustID.value)
   DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_CustDetailEdit"

Exit_cmdMoreInfo_Click:
   Exit Sub
Err_cmdMoreInfo_Click:
   MsgBox Err.Description
   Resume Exit_cmdMoreInfo_Click
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Close()
   On Error Resume Next
   DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "MyCustDetail"
End Sub
```

Comment: So far this is working for me, though when I click the button it pops up an error saying "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CustomerID =". Not sure what is wrong here, my table does have CustomerID as the autonumber, so it should be picking that up no?

Hm, just entered a string of text into the Customer Name text box (test) and it popped up this: Enter parameter Value (<title of msgbox) test _______ [Okay] [Cancel] I type 123 and push okay, then it pops up the form which is blank. I type Customer1 (the current only customer in that table for testing), and it's still blank.

Comment: In my example I am specifying the `CustomerID` by referencing a text box with the name of `txtCustID`.  Your control on your form for `CustomerID` May be different.  if you don't have one or don't need to show it to the user, then create one with the name `txtCustID`, Control Source of `CustomerID`, and set Visible to No.

Comment: Okay, the first error is gone. Though when I click the field in the subform, and then click More Info it pops up with Enter Parameter Value Customer1 ________. I type in anything, and it leaves form blank. I leave it blank, and it levels form blank.

I just added another record into the Customers table for testing, and I clicked that one this time (Customer2) and pushed more info. That seems to work, as instead of saying Customer1 _______ it says Customer2 _________. Can't seem to get it to pop up the more info in the form though.

Comment: You did change all of the names of everything in my example to match what is in your database, correct?  If you are hitting the button and it is asking you to enter the parameter, then it is not finding the control on your form.  The control is not on a sub form and the button on a main form, is it?

Comment: The button is on the form CustomerListF (the main form), and the control is also on the main form. I have changed everything in the code to what is in my database correctly.

Comment: Use Me!subformname("fieldname") to get the CustomerID.  I'm not sure about the rest of this idea but I just don't have time to help further.

Comment: Well, insert `msgbox(txtCustID.value)` before the `Dim` statement and let me know if it pops up a message box with the current CustomerID.

Comment: The msg box of Customer1 comes up, so yup. The msgbox appears. Went further and moved that code for the msgbox just abvoe the DoCmd.OpenForm line, and the msg box appears before the parameter message box. So it is one of the 7 lines after that. EDIT: In fact, it's the DoCmd.OpenForm line, I put the msgbox command after it and the parameter box happens first, then the msgbox.

Comment: If `Customer1` is actual value of your `CustomerID` field then you need to change the `WHERE` to what I have updated my answer to.  I assumed it would be a number, however, it appears to be a string.

Comment: Never mind about that error, I missed the small ' you added before the ". Now it says "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." If we are trying to pull the CustomerID here and not the actual name, it is indeed a number. Though if we are pulling the CustomerName column, then that is indeed a string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40193/discussion-between-linger-and-user2915607)

Comment: CustomerID is an autonumber; CustomerName is a string.

Comment: This would be much simpler using the *WhereCondition* option of `OpenForm` instead of altering a `QueryDef` every time.

Comment: **@HansUp**, I agree then you could just leave the query defined permanently.  Personal preference I don't pre-define queries, I just create them on the fly.

Comment: I think you're right about preferences, and I'm sure your approach works.  But it just seems like throwing way too much code at something which could be handled simply with a `DoCmd.OpenForm` one-liner.